# Applescript - expected end of line but found identifier

Tags: compiler-errors, applescript

I've been making some stuff in Applescript, to a friend of mine, and usually, with a bit of searching/researching, I'm able to overcome the problems I've been facing.
However... I found a problem I'm just not understanding.

For instance, I have:

```
tell application "Acrobat Distiller"
    Distill sourcePath inputFile1 adobePDFSettingsPath fullPathToJobOptions
end tell
```

If I replace it for:

```
tell application "/Applications/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro/Acrobat Distiller.app"
    Distill sourcePath inputFile1 adobePDFSettingsPath fullPathToJobOptions
end tell
```

I don't have any problem... but...
If I make something like:

```
set thePathToDistiller to "/Applications/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro/Acrobat Distiller.app"

tell application thePathToDistiller
    Distill sourcePath inputFile1 adobePDFSettingsPath fullPathToJobOptions
end tell
```

I get an error on the "Distill sourcePath inputFile1 adobePDFSettingsPath fullPathToJobOptions" line. More exactly on the "sourcePath" word.
The error is:
"Syntax error: expected end of line but found identifier"

What may be the problem here?
(thanks for any help you may give!) :)

Answer (score 4):

In

```
tell application "Acrobat Distiller"
```

the compiler can see the name of the program and load the program's dictionary at compile time. With the dictionary in hand, it knows what `Distill` means and what its parameters are.

Same with

```
tell application "/Applications/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro/Acrobat Distiller.app"
```

The name (actually path) of the program is right there in quotes, and the compiler can look at the app to extract its dictionary.

In

```
tell application thePathToDistiller
```

the compiler doesn't know which program you're interacting with. It's only at run time that the script knows the value stored in `thePathToDistiller`, and that's too late to let the compiler know which app's dictionary to look in.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After reading your answer I did understand the problem and I was hoping that Zero's code could work around the problem, but the same error ocurred. Does this means that what I'm trying to do... it's not possible in Applescript?

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap it around a "using terms from..." block, like this:

```
set thePathToDistiller to "/Applications/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro/Acrobat Distiller.app"
using terms from application "Acrobat Distiller"
tell application thePathToDistiller
    Distill sourcePath inputFile1 adobePDFSettingsPath fullPathToJobOptions
end tell
end using terms from
```

ADDITION:

I just tested it with iTunes;

```
set thePathToDistiller to "/Applications/iTunes.app"
using terms from application "iTunes"
    tell application thePathToDistiller
        playpause
    end tell
end using terms from
```

and that works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's strange however... I understand what you wrote (specially after reading the answer from ganbustein) but, even with your code, I keep having the same error.

Comment: Do you have different versions of Distiller stored? It could be that AppleScript uses a version that does not understand the "Distill" command or has another syntax for it (if you have such a version). Just a guess.

Comment: Strangely enough... this question is because my friend has 2 Distiller versions, but I don't have that have that problem. So I was trying to write a code to work on both computers without changing the code. But as answer to your question... no, I just have 1 Distiller. I guess I'll give up this path and go for another. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: I was going to tell you about using a "using terms from ..." block, but Zero beat me to it, so I +1-ed his answer, which should work. You do have to ensure that `thePathToDistiller` winds up with a value correct for the machine you run the script on, whichever machine that is.

Comment: Nope.... I really can't make it work! :( I think I'll progress the script on other directions and if I have the time I'll try again to make this work. One thing I found that would work was to use the "open" command for the "tell application" I didn't even needed the "using terms" block... but I need to change the quality of the distilling (using a joboption file), and I didn't found a command for it without using "Distill". Oh well... back to the "drawing board". Given the things that happened, should I consider any of the answers as correct? Thanks guys!!